# How to "lock" excel while interacting via COM

Tags: c#, excel, com

I have an .NET application that reads a database, does some analysis, and updates stats in an *Excel* spreadsheet using the COM interface.  I have the application to the point where it opens the workbook (or detects it, if it's already open), and finds the sheet it needs to update.

I'm encountering an issue where the user can still interact with *Excel* (close the application/workbook, change data, etc.) while my application is running.  I've considered hiding Excel while my app is chewing on data, but that is application-wide and prevents the user from interacting with *any* open spreadsheet.

Is there a way to lock Excel from changes through the COM interface, but still have it **viewable/readable** by the user?  Alternatively, is there a way to just **hide/lock** a single workbook?

Comment: You should use File.Move to move the file to a temp location, make your changes and then copy it back

Comment: @JMK I don't the OP's problem is with the user opening the file itself, more to do with the user interacting with the instance of Excel that has the file open.

Answer (score 3):

```
Application.Interactive=false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Application.Interactive=false;
```

as Sid suggests is your best bet
 I would suggest also changing:

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = false; // to avoid screen flicker
    Application.DisplayAlerts = false; // if you wish to suppress most excel messages
    Application.EnableEvents = false; // if there is vba in the workbook you wish to avoid triggering

    Application.Calulation = xlCalculationManual; // if it's a calc intensive automation
```

A good idea to collect your status pre your automation and set all of these properties back to their originals when you are finished with your automation.

Comment: If this is a commercial product or is used with other commercial products, I recommend against changing the `EnableEvents` property. Office products are a shared sandboxes -- other addins may be loaded which rely upon events to work properly. As an Office developer, it's important to strive for an add-in which is compatible with other add-ins, and setting `EnableEvents` to false is one of the most widely-implemented incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Would the `Worksheets("Sheet1").protect( <password> )` and `unprotect(<password>)` do the trick?

Comment: ((Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).EnableSelection = Excel.XlEnableSelection.xlUnlockedCells;
((Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Protect(Password: protectionPassword, AllowFormattingCells: false);

Comment: Protecting a sheet won't help!

Comment: Can you elaborate why protecting a sheet won't help? (because it effectively "lock" the sheet from modifications.

Comment: @gregsdennis Correct, but since you're in control (with your program), can't you lock the sheet from the beginning; then at each part of the code that need to update the sheet, you: unlock it, update, lock it again. And finally, at the end of the entire program, you unlock the sheet for good.

Comment: And to prevent users from closing the sheet, you can have a VBA code to handle the BeforeClose:

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If [SomeGlobalConditionFlag] = True Then Cancel = True
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

... The only real intelligent way to do this that I can think of is to create a new instance of an Excel Application, have that one hidden and to do your changes there.

then, if the workbook is already open, just notify the user and ask them to close it.

Comment: I could do that.  I would need to be sure to unhide the instance after my app completes since the user needs to perform some more operations within the sheet manually...

Comment: I have found that opening an Excel workbook from Explorer will cause Windows to maximise and make visible the instance of Excel that is hidden (assuming it is the only instance currently available).

Comment: @gregsdennis, That is very easy to do - Just create an ExcelApp object, set its `visible` property to False, at the end of the changes, set it's `visible` property to True and release the object without closing it, at that point, it just becomes another open app for the user to use... I do this often.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of doing it is to open and them immediately hide the entire workbook. That way you can still interact with it through Interop, but the user has no visibility to it (unless they specifically unhide it but I think a lot of users don't know how to do that).

```
xlWorkbook.Windows[1].Visible = false;
```